# why is nested OpenMP program is taking more time in executing?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

My OpenMP program of matrix multiplication which consists of nesting of for loops is taking more execution time than the non-nested version of the parallel program. This is the block where I have used nested parallelisation.

## pragma omp parallel

```
omp_set_nested(1);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            C[i][j]=0.; // set initial value of resulting matrix C = 0
            #pragma omp parallel for
                for(m=0;m<N;m++) {
                    C[i][j]=A[i][m]*B[m][j]+C[i][j];
                }
            printf("C:i=%d j=%d %f \n",i,j,C[i][j]);
      }
   }
```

Comment: How big is N and how many cpu cores are available in your computer or how many are you using?

Comment: Please edit your code sample. Right now it doesn't make sense. The `#pragma omp parallel` without a following block of code `{ ... }` applies only to the statement that follows it, in that case `omp_set_nested(1);`.

Comment: @fedepad my CPU consists of 16 cores.

Comment: @HristoIliev I corrected my code according to what you mentioned but still execution time is coming out to be more in nested program.

Comment: modified code is as follows : 
#pragma omp parallel 
    {
    //omp_set_nested(1);
   
#pragma omp parallel for

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
#pragma omp parallel for
        
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
        
            C[i][j]=0.; // set initial value of resulting matrix C = 0
           
            for(m=0;m<N;m++) {
                

                C[i][j]=A[i][m]*B[m][j]+C[i][j];
            }
            printf("C: i=%d  j=%d  %f  \n",i,j,C[i][j]);
        }
        }
}

Comment: @VaishaliAggarwal why is `//omp_set_nested(1)`? Did you comment it?

Comment: @fedepad yes, I did. I put it outside the #pragma omp parallel{...} instead. Is it correct ?

Comment: also by puutting omp_set_nested(10); , I am getting the following error :

libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: Nested parallelism is expensive. Starting a new parallel region on each iteration of each loop takes its toll. You cannot expect faster execution with nested parallelism in general and definitely not in that case in particular. Just count how many times a parallel region is created. Not to mention the data race in the innermost loop.

Comment: I second what @HristoIliev mentioned. The cost of creating the parallel regions could hide its benefits, especially if the number of iterations and the work done inside them is not much or expensive. That's why at the beginning I was asking how big is this N usually...

Comment: Depending on your choice of compiler, your inner omp pragmas may disable useful simd optimization.

Comment: so will my program show lesser execution time if I increase the number of cores?

Comment: How many threads do you think you are creating? How many do you think you should create? Are you aware of the cost of over-subscription (having more threads than logicalCPUs?) p.s. the fact that libgomp can't create all the threads you are asking for should be a hint here...